# Python ctypes create bytearray from void*

Tags: python, ctypes

I use ctypes to call a c function

```
void *crypto_data(void *buffer, int length, int *encrypt_len)
{
     void *encrypt = malloc(length+25);
     ...
     *encrypt_len = length + 25;
     return encrypt;
}
```

```
    lib.crypto_data.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_int, c_void_p]
    lib.crypto_data.restype = c_void_p

    my_len = c_int()
    out_buffer = c_int()
    out_buffer = lib.crypto_data(gzip_data, len(gzip_data), byref(my_len))
    print out_buffer #this out_buffer is the address of malloc
```

how do I create bytearray from this malloced memory?

Comment: What does your python code look like?

Comment: @AustinHastings I add my python code

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can create a new type using c_char or c_uchar and the buffer length:

```
mytype = ctypes.c_char * my_len
```

Then try to create an instance of that type `from_address` returned by your C function:

```
addr = crypto_data(args...)
array_of_char = mytype.from_address(addr)
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37988849/safer-way-to-expose-a-c-allocated-memory-buffer-using-numpy-ctypes) where `malloc` is used as the source of the data.